# Is it possible to draw to individual channels with Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, channel

I would like to draw in specific channels using Core Graphics.

Using the code below, each shape is drawn using a single channel color, but the second green filled rectangle will overwrite the previous red ellipse. I would like one ellipse to be only in the red channel and the square to be only in the green channel. I tried using transparency layers but they did not help.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50))
let squarePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50))

UIColor.red.setFill()
circlePath.fill()

UIColor.green.setFill()
squarePath.fill()
```

Is it possible to draw in individual channels? Or will I have to draw in individual bitmaps and combine them at the pixel level?

Comment: Drawing to individual channels is a futile pursuit. Even if you could do it, it would only work for drawing red, green and blue ovals. Any other colours would require transiency to properly work, so you should just directly do that. `UIColor.greeen.setFill()` is setting an opaque green, which is why you're seeing this overwriting behaviour.

Comment: The sample shown is over-simplistic. I need to be able to draw different shapes to different channels, and draw bitmaps in specific channels. As far as I can tell, transparency doesn't help.

Comment: (assuming I understand the question correctly) it doesn't matter. You only have 3 colour channels that model 3 fixed colour (r, g, b). Using these, you can only blend images that are pure red or pure green or pure blue. For example, you couldn't use this technique to draw a semi-transparent object behind some semi-transparent purple object.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using [`UIBezierPath.fill()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624371-fill) (which draws the bezier path as fully opaque), you need to use [`fill(with:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624366-fill), which allows you to specify a custom opacity as a `CGFloat` between `0` (fully transparent) and `1` (fully opaque).

There are multiple blend modes available (see [`CGBlendMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgblendmode)), which specify how partially transparent surfaces interact with each other. Multiply is a "sensible default", but you can play around with them and see which best matches your design. The blend modes are the same as those in Photoshop and such, so there's plenty of online tutorials, explanations and samples, such as https://photoshoptrainingchannel.com/blending-modes-explained/